# Cannot import name from Bert

Tags: python, import, spyder, bert-language-model, huggingface-tokenizers

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model    
import math
import os
import collections
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
from datetime import datetime
import bert
from bert import run_classifier
from bert import optimization
from bert import tokenization
from bert import modeling
```

I run the following block of code under python 3.10.9 after installing al relevant packages (including bert-tensorflow). However it always yields that some names like tokenization or run_classifier cannot be imported. I am basically copying code from huggingface's documentation. Does anyone know why this does not work?

Comment: Don't make us guess what the actual errors are.  Please edit the question and add the full error traceback message.

Comment: Also, please show us the exact command you used to install bert.

Comment: Is your python script itself named `bert.py`?

Comment: seems like package is missing. can you check if bert is installed using pip freeze command.

if package is missing in output, try running below commands


!pip install tensorflow==1.15.0
!pip install bert-tensorflow